# How to test Multi-part emails using outlook 2007?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, outlook-2007, thunderbird, multipart-alternative

I have developed an application in Delphi 7 which will send multi-part emails (both in Text and Html format). Now i want to test it using Outlook 2007.

I have tested each part separately by sending mail as text/plain and text/html. Now i need to test it together using multipart/alternative.

Please advice so that i can test both Text and Html parts.

Comment: So, which is your question? What did you try so far?

Comment: I have tested each part separately by sending mail as text/plain and text/html.

Comment: When you open your email in outlook, you can click on Options (on the ribbon), and at least, check the header of the email.

Comment: Yes, this i have checked and confirmed but i want to see how the Text part and Html part will look like in this type.

Comment: You need to be able to see the whole of the message source, something which outlook doesn't do. Set yourself up a gmail account and send the email to that, gmail lets you see the full source of an email.

Comment: As we receive HTML formatted mails in Outlook 2007, is there any setting to receive mails in plain text format?

Comment: Yes there is a setting for that. Tools > Trust Center... > Email Security > Read All Standard Mail as Plain Text. However that option will just convert the HTML to plain text. It will not show you the plain text part of the multipart email.

Comment: Yes i tried that as well but as you said not useful to see plain text part of this multi-part mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Thunderbird to test both the parts. There is a provision in this email client to view Plain text and HTML part by changing the view mode of the client.

ref: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2520/testing-the-plain-text-version/